# Dialogflow : Redirect to specific block based on date or day

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am currently building a quiz chatbot in dialogflow and I am wondering if it's possible to redirect users to a specific intent based on day or date.

Example:

1. > I would want users to take a daily quiz if the day is (Monday - Saturday).
2. > If its Sunday sends them to intent for a weekly quiz.
3. > If its the last day of the month send them to intent for the monthly quiz.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the user says "I wanna take a quiz" to your chatbot, which triggers the intent `take.quiz`. In the fulfilment code, you can set followupEvents based on the day/date it is.

Eg. if it's Monday-Saturday, do it like `agent.setFollowupEvent('take.quiz.daily');`
This will "redirect" it to daily quiz intent.

Something like

```
intentMap.set('take.quiz', takeQuiz);

function takeQuiz(agent) {
  //if day is Monday-Saturday
  agent.setFollowupEvent('take.quiz.daily')

  //if day is Sunday
  agent.setFollowupEvent('take.quiz.weekly')

  //if its last day of the month
  agent.setFollowupEvent('take.quiz.monthly')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intents capture *what the user says* and not what you're sending or how you handle what they have sent. So you can't "redirect" a user to a particular Intent.

Instead, you *can* determine, as part of your webhook fulfillment, what day of the week it is and send the appropriate question. You can set a parameter in the context to indicate which question you asked so when they answer, you know exactly which question they were answering. You would then have an Intent that accepts their answer and the fulfillment evaluates that answer and replies appropriately.